# Using Javascript to adjust a scroll bar in a modal dialog in Ruby-on-Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a Ruby-on-Rails web application that has a simple pop-up modal dialog.

When the user clicks on a button in the modal dialog, I would like to use a JavaScript function to modify the appearance of other components in the modal dialog.

I've been able to do this with several of the components; I can hide and/or enable various components in the JavaScript function.

The one thing I haven't been able to do, though, is adjust the scroll bar of the modal dialog.  Specifically, I need the scroll bar to be re-set to the very top of the modal dialog when the user clicks the button.

I've searched online, and it isn't that I haven't been able to find some possible solutions to this problem; it's just that so far none of them have worked.  I've tried using scrollTo, scroll, scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop.  So far, none of these have worked.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but if you do something like this it should fix it.

```
$(selector_for_button).click(function({
    $(selector_for_container_with_scroll_bar)[0].scrollTop = 0
})
```

where:

selector_for_button = button being clicked

selector_for_container_with_scroll_bar = the div the scroll bar belongs to.